# prevent newline in cut command

Tags: linux, newline, cut

Is it possible to `cut` a string without a line break?

`printf 'test.test'` prints the `test.test` without a newline.

But if I cut the output with `printf 'test.test' | cut -d. -f1` there's a newline behind `test`.

Comment: As I see you comment about a more generic problem, you'd better update the question with what you exactly want to do.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are many ways. In addition to isedev and fedorqui's answers, you could also do:

- `perl -ne '/^([^.]+)/ && print $1' <<< "test.test"`
- `cut -d. -f1 <<< "test.test" | tr -d $'\n'`
- `cut -d. -f1 <<< "test.test" | perl -pe 's/\n//'`
- `while read -d. i; do printf "%s" "$i"; done <<< "test.test`

Comment: Very comprehensive! +1 Is it necessary to use `$'\n'` on `tr -d`? To me, `tr -d '\n'` works fine.

Comment: @fedorqui huh, apparently not. I think I remember that it used to be but I might be wrong. Perhaps it depends on the `tr` implementation. I did it this way out of habit.

Comment: What does the `$` (dollar) in `tr -d $'\n'` mean?

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka it is not needed for GNU `tr` (the one on Linux machines) but it might be for other systems. It is a way of escaping, some programs can't deal with backslash escapes (things like `\n`, `\t` etc.) so we need to pass them that way. For example, compare `echo \n` and `echo $'\n'`.

Comment: `$'\n'` is bash string with escape sequences expanded (starts with `$'` and ends with `'`) containing a single newline character `\n`. Those strings work just like `echo -e` would do. Alternatively one could open an ordinary shell string, tap `<Enter>` key, then close the string, but it would be less concise.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have to use `cut`, you can achieve the same result with `awk`:

```
printf 'test.test' | awk -F. '{printf($1)}'
```

Comment: Thanks! First I had `awk 'NR==3 {printf "WiFi Signal Strength = " $3*10/7}' /proc/net/wireless | cut -d. -f1; printf "%%\n"` but the `cut` made a newline so I asked for a solution. Nevertheless if there's an easier way to solve it with one awk command, I would prefer it! (e.g. `awk 'NR==3 {print "WiFi Signal Strength = " $3*10/7 "%"}' /proc/net/wireless` and cut the output of `$3*10/7` after a dot)

Comment: how about: `printf("WiFi Signal Strength = %.0f%%",$3*10/7)` (the last %% corresponds to "%" in your awk code).

Comment: you should really accept @fedorqui's answer - it corresponds to the actual posted question. I posted my answer as a possible alternative for educational purposes only.

Comment: You're right! But anyway: thanks a lot! This is what I was looking for. :) (final command: `awk 'NR==3 {printf("WiFi Signal Strength = %.0f%%\n",$3*10/7)}' /proc/net/wireless`)

Comment: @gummiflummi you could also use `printf "%d", $3*10/7` to get the integer. In case you can also post another question so that isedev gets his deserved points.

Answer (score 5):

No that I know. `man cut` is quite short and doesn't reflect anything similar.

Instead, you can provide the `cut` output to `printf` with a [here-string](http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/x15683.html), so that the new line issue depends again on `printf`:

```
printf '%s' $(cut -d. -f1 <<< "test.test")
```